# Почему не удается установить две ОС на компьютер?

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, grub, dual-boot

Устанавливала раньше сначала Windows, после него - Linux так, чтобы обе ОС функционировали на одном компьютере, но находились на разных разделах диска. Делила диск с помощью acronis disk director suite. Все работало и загрузчик GRUB при включении компьютера отображал для запуска обе ОС.

Но что-то произошло. По-моему я меняла основной активный раздел тем же акронисом. После чего такой же алгоритм установки двух ОС больше не действует. Теперь, после установки Windows 7 и Linux (ROSA), при включении компьютера в загрузчике GRUB отображается только одна ОС, которая была установлена последней. Хотя обе ОС были установлены на разные разделы.

Comment: попробуйте заного в граб добавить вторую ОС. 
Может быть граб не ждет выбора ОС и сразу загружает по умолчанию?

Comment: Вы устанавливаете две оси и винды в загрузке нет. Верно? Возможно при установке линукса файлы загрузки винды удаляются. Было когда-то что винда была на одном диске а файлы загрузки (скрытые) на другом и когда второй диск форматировал перестала загружаться. Если я не ошибаюсь можно пройти двумя путями: 1) сделать активным(или основным. путаюсь) тот раздел где винда; 2) поменять места установки осей.

Comment: Все эти системы двойной загрузки работают до первого сбоя. Давно пора бы внести в БИОС аппаратную поддержку мультизагрузки, но грехи и требования обратной совместимости в рай не пускают.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Ну, такие попытки есть, по крайней мере на ноутбуках

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov Честно говоря, я не видел чтобы в БИОСе была поддержка двойной загрузки с одного диска. Даже (а может быть и тем более) в ноутах. Во всяком случае в моем ноуте (возраст 2 года) ее нет.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 На моих тоже нет. Но в каком-то из обзоров читал про такое. Поискал в хистори - не нашёл. Вкратце, что помню: на винте выделяется служебная область, с помощью которой EFI оперирует загрузками.

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov Ну дай-то Бог. :-) Ждем уже 30 лет а воз-БИОС и ныне там.

Comment: Спасибо большое за советы. Попробую применить на практике.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 wat? У меня на сотне машин стоит дуалбут с 2015 и ничего не ломается. Или ты про обновления win10?

Comment: @Senior Pomidor Если последней устанавливаю win7 - то выбора никакого не предлагает, сразу загружает win7 по умолчанию при включении компьютера. Если последним устанавливаю Linux ROSA, то  в GRUB-е отображаются три записи, относящиеся к линуксу, при этом win7 загрузчик не видит и не отображает. Как заново в GRUB добавить вторую ОС ? Что имеете ввиду? Ведь при установке линукса я выбираю предложение "установить GRUB на всю область HDD диска". Раньше при таком выборе у меня отображались обе ОС в GRUB при включении компьютера, а теперь только линукс.

Comment: @Алексей Осинный Верно. Попробую.